# What are the differences between a private network and a subnetwork?

Tags: networking, router, switch, subnet

And what are the advantages of creating subnetworks if computers are assigned different IP addresses from the same range and can communicate with each other also with switches?

Comment: I don't think you grasped the concept of a private network yet. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces for non-routable network spaces. These you can subdivide into subnetworks.

Comment: Please [don't cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) to multiple SE sites: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28697/what-are-the-differences-between-a-private-network-and-a-subnetwork

Answer (score 1):

- **Private Network**: A network not directly accesible from Internet because it uses  private addresses belonging to the ranges defined on [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) and [RFC 4193](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193).
- **Subnetwork**: When  a given range of IP addresses (public or private) is segmented, each segment is a subnetwork. Using subnetworks the network administrator can:
- Limitate broadcast traffic
- Control access to valuable assests as servers or communication links.
- Force the use of proxy servers to connect to internet.